# Norm of a map in Banach space

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a banach space and $f:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) \to (X,\mathcal{B})$ measurable function. I want to define $||f||_{L_1(X)}$. I saw this definition in a paper: $$||f||_{L_1(X)} = \int|f|d\mathbb{P}$$ but I don't understand what is $|f|$.

Comment: $|f|$ is supposed to $\|f\|$.

Comment: And ||f|| is the operator norm, right? Can you please elaborate and write the formula for it?

Comment: Are you aware of Bochner's integral?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only heard and don't know anything else about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is a Bannach Space, it is a Vectorspace bundled up with a Norm $\vert \cdot \vert$. $\vert f \vert \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; \; \omega \mapsto \vert f(\omega) \vert$.

Answer (score 0):

There are  several notions of measurabilty for Banach valued functions. In the definition of $\|f\|_{L^{1}(X)}$ we take $f$ to be strongly measurable which means it is a point-wise limit of simple functions . In this case the function $g: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ defined by $g(\omega)=\|f(\omega)\|$ is a measurable function and we define $\|f\|_{L^{1}(X)}$ as the integal of this non-negative measurable function w.r.t $\mathbb P$.